# Server Sider Rendering (SSR) React in Laravel with Vite not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, laravel, server-side-rendering, vite

I am trying to achieve SSR with react. Followed the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/vite#ssr). But it not working as expected. I kept the react app in `resources/js/react/`. And importing the App component in `resources/js/app.jsx`

```
import "./bootstrap";

import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "@/index.css";
import App from "@/App";
import reportWebVitals from "@/reportWebVitals";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("app")).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint.
reportWebVitals();
```

Here is my `vite.config.js`

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import laravel from "laravel-vite-plugin";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

import path from "path";

export default defineConfig({
    build: {
        manifest: true,
        minify: "terser",
        target: "esnext",
        terserOptions: {
            output: {
                comments: false, // This will remove all comments from the output files
            },
        },
    },
    plugins: [
        react(),
        laravel({
            input: ["resources/css/app.css", "resources/js/app.jsx"],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "resources/js/react/src"),
            "@assets": path.resolve(__dirname, "resources/js/react/src/assets/"),
            "@components": path.resolve(__dirname, "resources/js/react/src/components"),
            "@features": path.resolve(__dirname, "resources/js/react/src/features"),
            "@routes": path.resolve(__dirname, "resources/js/react/src/routes"),
            "@hooks": path.resolve(__dirname, "resources/js/react/src/hooks"),
        },
        extensions: [".js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".jsx"],
    },
});
```

Here is my `resources/js/ssr.js`

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import laravel from "laravel-vite-plugin";

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: "resources/js/app.jsx",
            ssr: "resources/js/ssr.js",
        }),
    ],
});
```

`package.json`

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build && vite build --ssr"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/react": "^18.0.27",
        "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.10",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
        "axios": "^1.1.2",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.7.4",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.4.23",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2",
        "terser": "^5.17.1",
        "vite": "^4.0.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        ...
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    }
}
```

when I run `npm run build`, it works, but according to docs I should have only `bootstrap/ssr/app.mjs` but it generates 2 files

```
✓ 87 modules transformed.
bootstrap/ssr/manifest.json      1.29 kB
bootstrap/ssr/app.mjs            0.03 kB
bootstrap/ssr/app2.mjs       1,616.05 kB
✓ built in 2.85s
```

then when I run
`node bootstrap/ssr/app2.mjs` (since ssr.mjs is not available and running app.mjs does nothing), it throws an error

```
/Users/name/Sites/MarketPlace/node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.cjs.js:410
    window = document.defaultView,
             ^

ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at getUrlBasedHistory (/Users/name/Sites/MarketPlace/node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.cjs.js:410:14)
    at Object.createBrowserHistory (/Users/name/Sites/MarketPlace/node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.cjs.js:227:10)
    at createBrowserRouter (/Users/name/Sites/MarketPlace/node_modules/react-router-dom/dist/umd/react-router-dom.development.js:235:23)
    at file:///Users/name/Sites/MarketPlace/bootstrap/ssr/app2.mjs:1:136246
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)

Node.js v18.16.0
```